# Dynamically import C# classes from other directories

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I have a Visual Studio C# project and a bunch of .cs (C# classes) in different directories inside one subdirectory called "OtherClasses". The directory structure will be:

```
<Visual C# Directory>
      <bin>
      <obj>
      <Properties>
      <OtherClasses>
           <Package1>
           <Package2>
```

So in each Package directory there are C# classes. My question is: Is there any way to inkove those classes from the main class inside the Visual C# directory?

Also I would like that if the user select Package N in the program then only the classes of that specific package are invoked. I don't know if it is possible to acheive this in some way.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you compiling them first or is this a loose collection of `.cs` files?

Comment: What do you mean "invoke those classes"?

Comment: @Travis: They are loose .cs files

Comment: @siride: I mean to use those classes from those .cs files, for example all classes have a method in common like calculate() and what I would do in the main program is to select a Package directory, the class and then call that method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create assemblies for each of the packages, and then load them dynamically based on what the user selects. You can even create these assemblies dynamically at run time by compiling the source files using the built in c# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio couldn't care less about the directory structure. Either the (.cs) files are included in the project and are compiled, or they aren't included in the project and thus aren't compiled. So regardless of what folder the different files are in, they will be able to invoke each other as long as their visibility (internal or public) permits it.

If you want to the user to be able to choose from different sets of classes, you'll have to use some other method to make the distinction besides relying on the directory of the source code.

**Edit**
This assuming you are compiling your .cs files as one project. If you are going to compile folders of code when the program runs, then how the code interacts will be determined by the specifics of the method you use.